Problems with the language of my URLs in Wordpress
Good morning, I have problems with the file languages ​​in Wordpress, what happens is that I am making a page in different languages, I use the Polylang plugin and I am uploading the names of the images in different languages, in Chinese or Hungarian they do not load the images. images because Wordpress does not detect the language, if for example I copy the link from Wordpress, it does not detect it, but if I copy the link from FTP, it does detect it, but it changes the characters from Chinese to something strange, but it works.
My question is: How can I prevent the URL from changing languages ​​and detect it in browsers? What Chartset should I use?
Before in Digital Ocean it worked, but they changed servers and we returned to Digital Ocean (precisely because of this problem) and now it doesn't detect it.
Thank you.


an example of the strange characters would help, keep in mind though that Chinese characters for example can't appear directly in a URL and have to be encoded, it may be the encoding that you're seeing as odd characters. If this is an issue with the user of Polylang though you'll need to raise this with their support as you can't ask questions about 3rd party plugins here. Can you reproduce this with no polylang? Note that the character set used for your database or for the page has nothing to do with this
